# Show that a tensor-train is contained in a recursive sequence of subspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, tensor-products, numerical-linear-algebra, tensor, tensor-calculus

Let

- $p\in\mathbb N$;
- $n_k\in\mathbb N$ and $\left(e^{(k)}_1,\ldots,e^{(k)}_{n_k}\right)$ denote the standard basis of $\mathbb R^{n_k}$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,p\}$;
- $u\in\bigotimes_{k=1}^p\mathbb R^{n_k}\cong\mathbb R^{\times_{k=1}^pn_k}$;
- $r_0,\ldots,r_p\in\mathbb N$ with $r_0=r_p=1$;
- $u^{(k)}\in\mathbb R^{r_{k-1}}\otimes\mathbb R^{n_k}\otimes\mathbb R^{r_k}$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,p\}$ with $$u=\sum_{j_0=1}^{r_0}\cdots\sum_{j_p=1}^{r_p}u^{(1)}_{j_0,\::\:,\:j_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes u^{(p)}_{j_{p-1},\::\:,\:j_p}\tag1,$$ where $u^{(k)}_{j_{k-1},\::\:,\:j_j}$ denotes the vector in $\mathbb R^{n_k}$ obtained from $u^{(k)}$ by fixing the first and last index $j_{k-1}$ and $j_k$, respectively.

> How can we show that there is a subspace $E_1$ of $\mathbb R^{n_1}$ with $\dim E_1=r_1$ and subspaces $E_k$ of $E_{k-1}\otimes\mathbb R^{n_k}$ with $\dim E_k=r_k$ for all $k\in\{2,\ldots,p\}$ such that $u\in E_p$?

I really struggle to see why this claim is true. If $p=1$, then $u=u^{(1)}_{1,\::\:,\:1}\in\mathbb R\otimes\mathbb R^{n_1}\otimes\mathbb R\cong\mathbb R^{n_1}$ and hence we may definie $E_1:=\mathbb Ru$.

Now, for $p>1$, I guess we need to use induction, but I'm not sure what precisely the induction hypotheses should be.

To keep things as simple as possible, just consider $p=2$. By a basis expansion of the second core, we can write $$u=\sum_{j_1=1}^{r_1}u^{(1)}_{1,\::\:,\:j_1}\otimes u^{(2)}_{j_1,\::\:,\:1}=\sum_{j_1=1}^{r_1}\sum_{i_2=1}^{d_2}u^{(2)}_{j_1i_21}u^{(1)}_{1,\::\:,\:j_1}\otimes e^{(2)}_{i_2}\tag2.$$ Now, the crucial observation seems to be that, for fixed $j_1\in\{1,\ldots,r_1\}$, $u^{(1)}_{1,\::\:,\:j_1}$ is just another instance of $(1)$ with $p=1$. So, some kind of induction hypotheses could be used to conclude. However, wouldn't this only yield the existence of a space $E_1^{(j_1)}\subseteq\mathbb R^{n_1}$ with $\dim E_1^{(j_1)}=1$ **which depends on $j_1$**? This seems to be problematic. My intention would be to define $E_1:=E_1^{(1)}+\cdots+E_1^{(r_1)}$, but all I know from $E_1$ is that $\dim E_1\le r_1$ ...